# First derivative of the transposition to be continuous

Tags: spectral-theory

In the document [That Sound the Same](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2975346) by S. J. Chapman page $127$, he explains the following concept :

> In order for the first derivative of the tranposition to be continuous
>   it is sufficient that
>
> **($1$)** Every fold lies along an outside edge of the new shape.
>
> **($2$)** Each edge of each copy of the original shape that lies in the interior of the final shape must be adjacent to its reflection on an
>   associated copy of the original shape.

After that fact, he cited that "*For example, the first derivative of the transposition is discontinuous across the lines ($1$) and ($2$) in Figure $4$*". I think because the English language is not my first language, I'm not able to well understand that line. Could anyone be able to explain in details why it is true?

**Clarification :** The method of transposition has also recently been used by Buser to generate new examples of isospectral plane domains. We could find an explanation of what is a transposition (or transplantation) in [Isospectral Riemann surfaces](http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/AIF/AIF_1986__36_2/AIF_1986__36_2_167_0/AIF_1986__36_2_167_0.pdf) by Peter Buser.

Please, if there are some corrections to inform me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "transposition" ? Is it in the sense of linear algebra ?

Comment: @JeanMarie This is all well explained in the document attached to document.

Comment: You can't expect people to read a whole text simply to answer a question. Any terms you use in your question you should define, unless they are in common use amongst mathematicians

Comment: @leibnewtz The document is quite short, it is not too difficult to find that definition.

Comment: I just don't understand the logic of flatly refusing to help people help you. Especially considering the steady stream of cosmetic edits; why not do something worthwhile, while you're at it? But, we won't be seeing eye-to-eye any time soon, I imagine...

Comment: I am a rather eager to learn, and I have the bad habit of wanting to force things. I understand @pjs36, I'll stop now. Sorry for the last edit.

Comment: @pjs36 The only thing I'll do is that if my question is not answered after a day or two, then I'll edit the question of improving the way in. I invite you to tell me if my approach is not adequate.